# Powershell разбить массив на маленькие файлы

Tags: powershell, split, txt

Есть массив такого вида:

```
string1
string2
string3
...
string100
```

Необходимо создать текстовые файлы с этими строчками, в каждом файле например по 10 строк.
Не могу сообразить, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = @()

$groupByCount = 7;
$rootFileScripts = "D:\scripts\";
$fileRootName = "defaultLogOutput";
$fileExtension = ".txt";

for($index = 0; $index -lt $arr.length; $index += $groupByCount) {
    for ($jIndex = 0; $jIndex -lt $groupByCount; $jIndex++) {
        $fileName = $rootFileScripts + $fileRootName + $index + $fileExtension;
        echo $arr[$index+$jIndex] | Out-File $fileName -Append;
    }
}
```